# SSO without Identity Provider Login Page

Tags: authentication, wso2, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 Identity Server for **SSO with saml** in my demo applications.

My requirement is User should provide Login credentials to Service Provider Login Page, not to Identity Provider page.

I followed following blog of Asela for the same purpose.

[http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/02/12/sso-without-identity-provider-login-page/][1]

This Implementation works fine for authenticating users which are in primary user store.

I tried it over my Secondary Read-only LDAP User store. And it is giving errors and not authenticating the users.

Following is the error stack from console :

> [2015-04-06 11:49:46,754] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.requestpath.basicauth.BasicAuthRequestPathAuthenticator}
>   -  Authentication failed for user tjayswal [2015-04-06 11:49:46,755] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.requestpath.basicauth.BasicAuthRequestPathAuthenticator}
>   -  Authentication Failed org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.exception.AuthenticationFailedException:
>   Authentication Failed     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.requestpath.basicauth.BasicAuthRequestPathAuthenticator.processAuthenticationResponse(BasicAuthRequestPathAuthenticator.java:94)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.process(AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.java:61)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultRequestPathBasedSequenceHandler.handle(DefaultRequestPathBasedSequenceHandler.java:72)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.handle(DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.java:114)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator.handle(DefaultRequestCoordinator.java:94)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doPost(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:54)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doGet(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:44)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [2015-04-06 11:49:46,756]
>   ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultRequestPathBasedSequenceHandler}
>   -  Authentication Failed org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.exception.AuthenticationFailedException:
>   Authentication Failed     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.requestpath.basicauth.BasicAuthRequestPathAuthenticator.processAuthenticationResponse(BasicAuthRequestPathAuthenticator.java:115)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.process(AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.java:61)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultRequestPathBasedSequenceHandler.handle(DefaultRequestPathBasedSequenceHandler.java:72)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.handle(DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.java:114)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator.handle(DefaultRequestCoordinator.java:94)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doPost(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:54)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doGet(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:44)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

**Important** :

I am using WSO2 **Identity Server 5.0 latest patch updated** version.

Please someone guide me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also face same issues during my POC. I think this problem generate b'cos of mistake in LDAP configuration with IS.

check secondary user store xml file created under

> IS_HOME/repository/deployment/server/userstores/'userstorename'.xml

and check all configuration are proper according to standard practice.

This has helped me to solve my problem as I was missing one ;(semicolon)
in

> userNameSearchFilter

property.